# mysql dump 200DB ~ 40GB from one server to another

Tags: linux, ssh, mysql

What would be the most efficient way for me to export 200 databases with a total of 40GB of data, and import them into another server?  I was originally planning on running a script that would export each DB to their own sql file, and then import them into the new server.  If this is the best way, are there some additional flags i can pass to the mysqldump that will speed it up?

The other option I saw was to directly pipe the mysqldump into an import over SSH.  Would this be a better option?  If so could you provide some info on what the script might look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the servers can ping each other you could use PIPES to do so:

```
mysqldump -hHOST_FROM -u -p db-name | mysql -hHOST_TO -u -p db-name
```

Straightforward!

**[EDIT]**

Answer for your question:

```
mysqldump -hHOST_FROM -u -p --all | mysql -hHOST_TO -u -p
```

Comment: How would I go about using this command if the database doesn't exist on the remote server?  All of the databases i need to import also need to be created on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and fastest way is to use percona xtrabackup to take hot backups. It is very fast and you can use it on live system whereas mysqldump can cause locking. Please avoid copying /var/lib directory to other server in case of Innodb, this would have very bad effects.

Try percona xtrabackup, here is some more information on this on installation and configuration. [Link here](http://blog.cloudydna.com/installing-percona-xtrabackup-step-by-step-guide/).

Comment: I ended up going with the mysql dump pipe to remote server option due the the simplicity.  However, I did see some other references around the web about xtrabackup and definitely looks like useful.  I'll be preforming the same task in the near future so I'll have to try it out then.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If both mysql servers  will have same dbs and config I think the best method is to copy the /var/lib/mysql dir using rsync. Stop servers before doing the copy to avoid table corruption

Answer (score -2):

1. Export MySQL database using SSH with the command

`mysqldump -p -u username database_name > dbname.sql`

1. Move the dump using wget from the new server SSH.

`wget http://www.domainname.com/dbname.sql`

1. Import the MySQL database using SSH with the command

`mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql`

Done!!